# PHP array Value always return

Tags: php

Trying to get a value out of an array and it never works. I am trying to get the value of "Image_id". My loop is as follows:

```
 foreach($gallery as $gimage) { 
     var_dump($gimage);
     echo $gimage["Image_id"];
 }
```

The value of $gallery is:

```
Array(10) { [0]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I00000KPOFjox2AQ" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [1]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I00008BG9UDA9DeI" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [2]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000bpb88hlOpt8" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [3]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000vE8GZ8p_d5E" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [4]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000xDm267iNEKw" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [5]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I00004DMdHWsflCA" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [6]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000zoAFd_.Ywgo" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [7]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I00003TmAVNDJ7pE" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [8]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000kf4wIww90l0" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } [9]=> Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I0000XbVhViGQiyk" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" } }
```

When I var_dump($gimage) I get:

```
Array(2) { ["Image_id"]=> String(16) "I00000KPOFjox2AQ" ["Gallery_id"]=> String(16) "G0000bLsNtDO2rtg" }
```

But this always fails:

```
echo $gimage["Image_id"];
```

I have tried

```
echo $gimage[0]["Image_id"];
echo $gimage[0];
```

Comment: It fails __how__?

Comment: Add this inner foreach loop to your code and tell us the exact output: `foreach($gimage as $key => $value){var_dump($key);}`

Comment: Share the full code. You can var_dump at different line of the echo.

Comment: @Rizier123: this is the result I get:   String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id" String(8) "Image_id" String(10) "Gallery_id"

Comment: @u_mulder I get nothing back, not errors, nothing.

Comment: @kig If this is your output then you're definitely not showing us something. You need to provide us a [mcve]

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for helping. I edited the question to include the value of $gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
var_dump($gimage[])
```